# how do I enable Free Shipping in WooCommerce using function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Wordpress 4.5.2
WooCommerce 2.5.5

By default I have disabled the free shipping option in woocommerce and only enabled the Flat Rate shipping.

Now if the cart total is >=20 then only I want to enable the Free Shipping option else use the Flat Rate.

This is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'apply_free_shipping_coupon' );

function apply_free_shipping_coupon($aa)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    global $cart_total_inc_vat;
    $cart_total_inc_vat =  $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
    //echo $cart_total_inc_vat;
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available', 'free_shipping_based_on_cart_shipping_class' );
    }
}

function free_shipping_based_on_cart_shipping_class( $is_available ) 
{
    $found = false;
    if($cart_total_inc_vat >=20)
    {
        $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart();

      foreach ( $cart_items as $cart_item )
      {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $class   = $product->get_shipping_class();

        if ( 'free_shipping' === $class ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
      }
      $found = true;
    }
    return $is_available && $found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce -> Settings -> Shipping -> Free Shipping. 
You can change the settings to allow free shipping above $20.

Comment: Hi Gertjan, I was using it before but if I use a discount coupon and cart goes < 20 and it doesn't give free shipping, and that's why I am using those API hooks in the code I posted.